# div resized according to the number of divs in a row

Tags: javascript, html, resize, width, row

I'm currently building an online editor, and I was wondering if it is possible to resize a `<div>` according to the number of `div`s that are not in a `display:none` state.

For example, I have a row with three `div` columns, each of them are 32% large, I want that if one is in a `display:none` state the two others will be 48% large.

So the code I have is in the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="showHide('.text1')" checked="" /> 
<input type="checkbox" onclick="showHide('.text2')" checked="" /> 
<input type="checkbox" onclick="showHide('.text3')" checked="" /> 

<div id="line1">
    <div id="text1"></div>
    <div id="text2"></div>
    <div id="text3"></div>
</div>
```

and in the javascript only this using jquery:

```
function showHide(divId)
{$(divId).slideToggle('slow');}
```

What I want is that when I uncheck any of the text, the two other remaining go from 33% to 50%, and if another one is removed from 50% to 100%.

Comment: If you're showing and hiding `div`s with JavaScript, it's easy to count the remaining visible divs and apply a width to them. Please post your code to get a more specific answer.

Comment: I'm using jquery to show and hide the div, but I don't know how to do to count the remaining div with a display different than none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML is something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

After you've applied the `display` values, you could use [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to figure out how many elements are visible, and apply a width based on that:

```
// select visible children
var visibleDivs = $('.container div:visible');

// use whatever width calculation you'd like...
var targetWidth = 100 / visibleDivs.length - 1;

// apply the width to the divs
visibleDivs.width(targetWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just css, here,

```
<div class="container">
<span>test</span><span>test2</span><span>test3</span></div>



.container {
display: table;
width: 100%;}
.container > span {
display: table-cell;
width: auto;
text-align: center;}
```